# How can I install the AWS Instance Profile Metadata service on my local machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'd like my install script to be able to work locally and on the ec2 instance. Currently on my local machine there is nothing at 169.254.169.254 (when using curl it just times out). I've gone through the installation steps for the aws cli and can successfully run commands through the cli, but there are other tools (out of my control) that hit the 169.254.169.254 endpoint.

Is there a way to install the metadata service locally?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do it?

Comment: @Marcin I was never able to test locally unfortunately. Seems amazon doesn't want you to install the metadata service seeing as they don't mention how to install it anywhere in the docs. Doesn't make much sense why not though. It just needs to add a record to /etc/hosts and respond with the same data that's in ~/.aws/credentials.

Comment: You can always ask AWS support why not.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to install the metadata service locally?

Sadly you can't do this. The address is only valid from AWS. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html):

> The IP addresses are link-local address and are valid **only from the instance**.